# How can I preview changes to design or to blocks?

Tags: image-preview, home

lets say i add new blocks to the home page. or change some other things. how can I let other people preview it before releasing? any extension or is it built in?

thanks much

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is to create separate vhost with development version. If you are using some control version (git, svn) then you can create dev branch for the second vhost and update that vhost with that branch. When changes are approved you will have to only merge them to production branch and update production server.

Any other solutions would need to at least have configuration of the dev database in order not to mix things up as well as separate config for which modules are enabled on production and which one on the dev version.

Answer (score 1):

Magento doesn't have such a functionality. I suggest using a staging environment.